# How to check if a variable is loaded in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object

How do I see if a certain object has been loaded, and if not, how can it be loaded, like the following?

```
if (!isObjectLoaded(someVar)) {
    someVar= loadObject();
}
```

Answer (score 37, accepted):

If it is an object then you should just be able to check to see if it is [null](http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/g/rnull.htm) or [undefined](http://javascript.about.com/od/reference/g/sundefined.htm) and then load it if it is.

```
if (myObject === null || myObject === undefined) {
   myObject = loadObject();
}
```

Using the [typeof](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml) function is also an option as it returns the type of the object provided. However, it will return [null or undefined](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/determinevar2.shtml) if the object has not been loaded so it might boil down a bit to personal preference in regards to readability.

Comment: Isn't a test like if (myObject == null) (or undefined) enough, since that's precisely the point of the simple equality? Or I am missing something?

Comment: @PhiLho - Depending upon the object type, the object could be null, or it could be undefined. JavaScript treats them as two different things.

Comment: @Rob @PhiLho This: `x == null` is equivalent to this: `x === null || x === undefined` (under the condition that the global variable `undefined` hasn't been modified). Therefore, instead of your expression you can just write `myObject == null`. It's not only smaller, but also more robust since it's indifferent to assignments to the variable `undefined`.

Answer (score 27):

```
if(typeof(o) != 'object') o = loadObject();
```

Comment: Remember that typeof returns "object" for nulls, so you'll probably want something like [if(null !== x && 'object' == typeof(x)){]

Answer (score 5):

```
myObject = myObject || loadObject();
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "loaded"... does the variable `object` exist and simply doesn't have the type you want? In that case, you'll want something like:

```
function isObjectType(obj, type) {
    return !!(obj && type && type.prototype && obj.constructor == type.prototype.constructor);
}
```

and then use `if (isObjectType(object, MyType)) { object = loadObject(); }`.

If `object` is not populated with anything before your test (ie - `typeof object === 'undefined'`) then you just need:

```
if ('undefined' === typeof object) { object = loadObject(); }
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably want to see if a given object is *defined*

Especially if its done in an asynchronous thread with a setTimeout to check when it turns up.

```
  var generate = function()
  { 
      window.foo = {}; 
  }; 
  var i = 0;
  var detect = function()
  {
     if( typeof window.foo == "undefined" ) 
     {
           alert( "Created!"); 
           clearInterval( i );
     }
   };
   setTimeout( generate, 15000 ); 
   i = setInterval( detect, 100 );
```

should in theory detect when window.foo comes into existance.

Answer (score 3):

If by loaded you mean defined, you can check the type of the variable with the typeof function. **HOWEVER** typeof has a few quirks, and will identify an Object, an Array, and a **null** as an object

```
alert(typeof(null));
```

Identifying a null as a defined object would probably cause your program to fail, so check with something like

```
if(null !== x && 'object' == typeof(x)){
    alert("Hey, It's an object or an array; good enough!");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to detect a custom object:

```
// craete a custom object
function MyObject(){

}

// check if it's the right kind of object
if(!(object instanceof MyObject)){
   object = new MyObject();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also just use a shortcut `if(obj)`

Answer (score 1):

`typeof(obj)` would return "object" for an object of a class among other possible values.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!("someVar" in window)) {
  someVar = loadObject();
}
```

will tell you whether any JS has previously assigned to the global `someVar` or declared a top-level `var someVar`.

That will work even if the loaded value is `undefined`.